# Where is located the code of the hook I want to modify in Prestashop?

Tags: templates, location, hook, prestashop, product

I want to add an information on my product page on prestashop.

Add a text (in red on the screen) under the “Ajouter au panier” (or “Add to Cart”) button to specify the delivery date for every products.

See on the screenshot :
[image]

I have found which code generate the container (the blue one on the screen) :

> product.tpl

`{hook h='displayBeforePanier'}`

But I can’t find where the code who’s hooked is located.
Can someone explain me where this code is or where to find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check the option `Show invisible hook` to find this hook in `Modules > Positions`.

This code belong to the module `FO Quantity Prices` by OleaCorner.
The template of this hook is accessible in `modules/oleafoquantityprices/prices_info.tpl`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom hook. You should search in your **modules** files for the function `hookDisplayBeforePanier()`. Or search for it in all files.

Or you can go to your backoffice `Modules > Positions` page and try to look for this hook - you will find the module which is using it.